# Аргументы шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте, подскажите, что можно передать в аргумент шаблона по ссылке (всего 4 варианта): 1 - тип, 2 константу целого типа, 3 - , 4- ? Спасибо!

**Добавлено.**

Вот:

```
template<class Type>
class r
{
};
```

Что можно в Type передать по ссылке из main (сейчас передаю просто char):

```
void main{
    r<char> b;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

В шаблоны можно передавать любые типы, как стандартные, так и пользовательские, в том числе структуры и классы. Но нужно помнить, что в случае таких сложных типов следует позаботиться о специализации шаблонных функций или о перегрузке операторов в классах, чтобы не возникало ошибок при проведении операций с такими переменными.

Константа - это не тип данных. Но в методы класса, созданного на основе шаблона, конечно, можно передавать константы в качестве аргументов, если позволяет их тип.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве параметра шаблона можно указывать уже существующий тип, если Вы про это. 
Например

```
template<int size, class _T>
class MyArray
{
};
```

И потом в качестве параметра size передать константу.
`MyArray<5, double> arr;`